# how to make case insensivity for css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, case, selector

this code below I tried

```
queryselector('img[src*="http://webserver.com/upload/"]');
```

doesn't match `<img src="http://WebServer.com/upload/file.jpg">`

this line can't be changed and neither can selector be changed...
any ways to do a case insensitive comparation of `src` attribute?

plus: `input[value='search' i]` works in no browser currently... and the code is supposted to run for endusers, not just myself...

Comment: Basically...NO. CSS is case sensitive and if you can't change the HTML or selector you're out of luck. You *could* add another correct selector below the first though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085262/jquery-validate-how-do-i-ignore-letter-case

Comment: @Paulie_D: Case insensitive selectors are there as part of Selectors Module 4 but (a) it has low browser support and (b) it doesn't seem to be working with JS selector API - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671238/css-selector-case-insensitive-for-attributes

Comment: @Harry: It should work, the only selectors that aren't guaranteed to work in the Selectors API are dynamic pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements - for all other purposes the selectors supported in CSS are a subset of the ones in the Selectors API, not the other way around. I left a comment on the other answer.

Comment: Oh thanks @BoltClock I just saw the comment in the other answer and hadn't bothered to check :D